Display a field form a foreign key onto a template
class Product(models.Model):
    
    model=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    serial=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    hd_size=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    ram=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    processor=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    date_purchased = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

I am trying to display the data from this model but the foreign key column "employee" is not showing on the template
Here is my template
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form method= 'POST' id="product-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.id }}">
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
            <label for="model" class="control-label">Model</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="model" name="model" value="{{ product.model}}" required>
                </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
            <label for="serial" class="control-label">Serial No</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="serial" name="serial" value="{{ product.serial}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
            <label for="hd_size" class="control-label">HD Size</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="hd_size" name="hd_size" value="{{ product.hd_size}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
            <label for="ram" class="control-label">RAM</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="ram" name="ram" value="{{ product.ram}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
            <label for="processor" class="control-label">Processor</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="processor" name="processor" value="{{ product.processor}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
            <label for="product_type" class="control-label">Type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="product_type" name="product_type" value="{{ product.product_type}}" required>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
                <label for="date_purchased" class="control-label">date purchased</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control rounded-0" id="date_purchased" name="date_purchased" value="{{ product.date_purchased}}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="employee">Employee:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="employee" name="employee">
                  {% for employee in form.employee.field.queryset %}
                  <option value="{{ employee.address }}">{{ employee.address }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>     
  
    </form>
</div>

The field with the foreign key is supposed to allow me have dropdown where i can selectfrom a list of employee email address from the employee table
Here is my views.py
# product
@login_required
def product_mgt(request):
    context['page_title'] = "Computer List"
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context['products'] = products

    return render(request, 'product_mgt.html', context)

@login_required
def save_product(request):
    resp = {'status':'failed','msg':''}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if (request.POST['id']).isnumeric():
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
        else:
            product = None
        if product is None:
            form = SaveProduct(request.POST)
        else:
            form = SaveProduct(request.POST, instance= product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            messages.success(request, 'Computer has been saved successfully.')
            resp['status'] = 'success'
            
        else:
            for fields in form:
                for error in fields.errors:
                    resp['msg'] += str(error + "<br>")
    else:
        resp['msg'] = 'No data has been sent.'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), content_type = 'application/json')
     


Can you share your view and the template that how you are showing this ForeignKey field?

Show us your template code. It's possible to show employee data on template.

Just shared the template and the view

Thank you. I have managed to solve the issue by creating a separate form to input the foreign key field then save using this view
def assign_employee_to_product(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AssignEmployeeForm(request.POST, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Employee has been assigned a computer successfully.')
            
            
    else:
        form = AssignEmployeeForm(instance=product)
    return render(request, 'assign.html', {'form': form, 'product': product})

